# Array of pointers for a class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is the code I have:

```
int x, y;
Point** points;
int i = 10;
points = new Point*[i];
    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        points[a] = new Point(x, y);
    }
```

But the problem is, that after the inputs are scanned only one of the array elements manage to survive(In other words, only the first pointer gets a value and the others won't get into the array despite explicitly programming for). And when I retrieve the size of the array(with sizeof(points)) it returns 11(!)

As I am a little bit new to c++, so any help in code from would be also appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason to manually `new` stuff? `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` are your friends.

Comment: Post the code for Point class and what output you want

Comment: The point class just holds an x, and a y, nothing complicated there. Well except it doesn't have any default constructors.(which doesn't matter)

Comment: Ok. The code seems to be fine here. Can you post the part of code where you are trying to output the results?

Comment: Can you post the printing code too?

Comment: Why are you using `scanf` in C++ code?

Comment: There isn't any printing code there, this is the result that the debugger gives me.

Comment: Also, can we even use vectors on something which is not a primitive type?

Comment: You can use vector to store almost anything.

Comment: If there is no printing code how are you saying that "only the first pointer gets a value and the others won't get into the array" ?

Comment: Can you give me an example of this. Thanks

Comment: @lkn2993 I see nothing immediately wrong with your code. Regarding other implementation concepts, if the size is known at compile-time, you should use either `std::array<Point, N>` (if your tools are C++11 compliant) or simply `Point[N]`, where `N` is the known constant size. If it is *not* known, you should be using `std::vector<Point>`. See for [`std::array<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for more info. And note: `std::vector<>` is arguable the most used standard container in the entire library.

Comment: Just one more question, how can I pass a vector as a pointer?

Comment: [See it live](http://ideone.com/Y9XY5O). And to answer your question about passing it as a "pointer", assuming it is non-empty, you can access the elements using the `.data()` member. Its in the documentation I linked.

Comment: That should do it. Thanks.